# Unit norm equiangular frame condition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am facing the following problem.

Starting from the matrix
$$
C=\sum_{i=1}^{K}w_iw_i^T,\;\;w_i\in \mathbb{R}^2,\;\;||w_i||_2=1,\;\;K>2
$$
I would like to find a norm on $C$ such that
$$
||C||=\sum_{i,j=1}^K (w_i^Tw_j)^n
$$
with $n>2$. Any choice of such $n$ will work.

Alternatively also a norm such that
$$
||C||=max_{i\neq j}|w_i^Tw_j|
$$
would work.

Minimizing one of these two quantities guarantees that  $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^{K}$ is an equiangular frame, that is what I am looking for (starting from $C$).

Many thanks.

Fabio